# How to save url <str:> part in Django Class Based View context

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am struggling to get the value uuid_contrat in my url into my views' context. This is what I have got so far:

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from applications.views import *
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:uuid_contrat>/', ApplicationListView.as_view(), name="applications") ,
]
```

**views.py**

```
class ApplicationListView(ListView):
    model = ViewDevpermissionapplicationuser
    template_name = 'applications/applications.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update(
            user= self.request.session.get('user', {'is_authenticated' : False})
        )
        
       
        context['uuid_contrat'] = self.request.GET.get('uuid_contrat')
        
        return  context
```

I tried using request.GET.get but it isn't working, any suggestions ?

Comment: I suggest you to run your program in debug mode and step through. Then you can view the current runtime objects in detail and exactly find out what object you need to access. 
I dont see any request object iin your method, so I am not sure where you got it from. But I am not familiar with the way you setup your view, I mostly work with rest_framework

Comment: I am using class based views, hence I can call it with self.request. Thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: @user19632683 You haven't call the `super()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `self.kwargs['uuid_contrat']` to fetch the uuid from the url kwargs so:

```py
class ApplicationListView(ListView):
    model = ViewDevpermissionapplicationuser
    template_name = 'applications/applications.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update(
            user=self.request.session.get('user', {'is_authenticated': False})
        )

        context['uuid_contrat'] = self.kwargs['uuid_contrat']

        return context
```